# How to move all the density versions of resource in one command?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got many image resources in several densities, and I'd like to move them into an other module. Moving them one by one takes a long time, especially because Android Studio's Project window goes into some kind of flickering on every file move.

For exemple, I'd like to move the following resources:

```
module1/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/image_a.png
module1/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/image_a.png
module1/src/main/res/drawable-xdpi/image_a.png
module1/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/image_a.png
```

into

```
module2/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/image_a.png
module2/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/image_a.png
module2/src/main/res/drawable-xdpi/image_a.png
module2/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/image_a.png
```

Is it possible to move the four files in one go, instead of having to do a `Move...` on each file ?

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution.

1. In module2 project, right click the res folde, then select the **New > Image Asset** menu.

[image]

2. Then, in the **Configure Image Asset** window, select the right *Icon Type* and , in the *source asset* section, select *Image* as *Asset Type* and enter the path to the xxhdpi version of the image from module1. You may need to pay attention to the other fields before clicking the *Next* button.

This will automatically generate all the image resources.

Comment: Interesting thanks, but the transparency of the original image is lost with this solution